# Como manipular Caracteres em Strings em Python

Tags: python, c

Eu queria saber como eu posso manipular caracteres em Python. Em C, eu consigo fazer isso de somar 1 a um caractere, se eu digitar "a" por exemplo, ele soma 1, e o "a" vai virar "b". Exemplo:

```
char string[20];
    printf ("Digite uma String: ");
    scanf ("%19[^\n]", string);

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i+=1)
    {
            string[i] += 1;
    }
```

Teria Alguma forma de eu fazer algo semelhante em Python? 
Eu sei que Existem funções para transformar a letra de minusculo para maiusculo e vice versa, mas eu queria mesmo era mudar as letras de acordo com a Tabela Ascii, mudar os caracteres de uma string, um a um. Teria como manipular os caracteres de uma string em python do mesmo jeito que eu manipulo em C?

Comment: Embora eu não ache que esta seja uma das melhores perguntas do site, não vejo nada que justifique o seu fechamento. Votei para reabrir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, mas não tão diretamente quando C.

Em C, o caractere `'a'` é armazenado na memória como o byte 01100001, que em decimal é o número 97. Quando você adiciona 1 ao valor, o computador somará o 1 ao byte, obtendo 01100010, que é o número 98 em decimal e a letra `'b'` quando analisada como caractere.

No Python, os objetos são muito mais complexos que isso. Junto com os próprios valores há também implementado inúmeros campos e métodos relacionados ao objeto e, assim, não conseguirá fazer uma relação direta entre um caractere e um número. Porém, você consegue fazer a mesma coisa que ocorre em C, mas manualmente, que é obter o respectivo decimal relacionado ao seu caractere, somar 1 e depois verificar qual é o caractere relacionado ao resultado.

Para tal, pode utilizar as funções `ord` e `chr`.

```
letra_a = 'a'
inteiro_a = ord(letra_a)
inteiro_b = inteiro_a + 1
letra_b = chr(inteiro_b)
```

Ou apenas, `letra_b = chr(ord('a')+1)`. A função `ord`, para o parâmetro `'a'` retornará o número inteiro 97. Somado 1 obtém-se 98 que através da função `chr` obtém-se o caractere `'b'`.